# Outlook Display Change in High Sierra

Tags: display, email

When I click on an incoming message instead of enlarging to fill the screen as always has been the case, I now get a postcard sized enlargement of the message superimposed atop the Message List and the Preview Screen.  How do I change the setting so a click on the message will go directly to enlarging the message to fill the screen?

Answer (score 1):

Open your message app and click on the Window menu item. Near the top of the menu is a setting for Zoom. Click on this and leave it. Whenever you open a message it should open in full screen. To turn zoom off, click on the option again. Once you've clicked zoom it will be remembered if you quit messages and start again.